# Getting the right tag with BeautifulSoup (problem)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to get the "tbody" element from the html of this website, but the command seems to include the "thead" element as well. Why?

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests 

import re

site1 = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements")

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(site1.text, "html.parser")
    
body_ = soup1.tbody

print(body_.contents[0])
```

This prints me the first child of *"thead"* element although it should give me the first child of *"tbody"*.

output:

```
<tr>
<th colspan="13">List of chemical elements
</th></tr>
```

Now I didn't copy the source code here since it is too large but here is a link to the site of the source code used:

[site of source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements)

Comment: If it is only the Table of the elements you are after try `pandas.read_html` (more information [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html)). This command will automatically retrieve all the data within the `<table>`tag of the `html` page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `print(soup1)` you will see that there's another `<tbody>` before the main table. So you need to be more specific what do you want to select.

For example:

```
site1 = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements")
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(site1.text, "html.parser")

body_ = soup1.select_one('tbody:has(tr)')
for row in body_.select('tr:has(td)')[:-1]:
    tds= [td.get_text(strip=True, separator=' ') for td in row.select('td')]
    print(*tds[:3], sep='\t')  # <-- here only print first three columns for example
```

Prints:

```
1   H   Hydrogen
2   He  Helium
3   Li  Lithium
4   Be  Beryllium
5   B   Boron
6   C   Carbon
7   N   Nitrogen
8   O   Oxygen

...

113 Nh  Nihonium
114 Fl  Flerovium
115 Mc  Moscovium
116 Lv  Livermorium
117 Ts  Tennessine
118 Og  Oganesson
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find_all()` method on `soup1` to extract the elements you need:

```
find_all(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, limit=None, **kwargs)
    Extracts a list of Tag objects that match the given
    criteria.  You can specify the name of the Tag and any
    attributes you want the Tag to have.

    The value of a key-value pair in the 'attrs' map can be a
    string, a list of strings, a regular expression object, or a
    callable that takes a string and returns whether or not the
    string matches for some custom definition of 'matches'. The
    same is true of the tag name.
```

There are some more detailed examples [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Answer (score 0):

For getting this table you can use simply pandas `pd.read_html()` method:

```
import pandas as pd

url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chemical_elements"

df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
```

Output will be:

[image]